# SQL Server Replication - No replicated transactions are available

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, transactional-replication

I have created a publisher (on sql server 2008 r2), create transaction replication and have created a new database on subscriber sql instance (SQL Server 2012 Express).
After I have created a new subscription on SQL Server 2012 Express.

But My new database had't been updated via synchronization.
On server SQL server 2008 r2 via Replication monitor I can see that status is Uninitialized subscription for SQL Server 2012 Express and in details *No replicated transactions are available*. message

How I can fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error states that your subscription is uninitialized.

You need to create the initial snapshot. Right-click the publication under the **Local Publications** folder at the Publisher and click **View Snapshot Agent Status**. Then click Start. Once the snapshot is generated, synchronize your subscription to apply the snapshot.

This is covered in [Create and Apply the Initial Snapshot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151788.aspx).

Comment: it is dos't help Uninitialized subscription  is still be visible, Snapshot had been done. I really don't know what to do

Comment: Please verify the Log Reader Agent is running. In Replication Monitor, navigate to the Agents tab, and select Log Reader Agent from the drop down.  Is there an error?  Also, you right-click on your publication -> View Log Reader Agent Status...

Comment: Log Reader Agent status Running////

Comment: You may need to look into security related issues. Temporarily give subscriber account sysadmin rights and make sure it is in the publication access list. BOL has great info on these.

Comment: Drop the subscription and try again.  Ensure the subscription has all of the required permissions in Replication Agent Security Model (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).